Discord Bot, does not run. But why?
I don't know why, but my bot is not responding to my command...
Do you know why?
The bot is online and connected to my server and has all the necessary permissions to write texts.
But unfortunately the bot does not write when I send a command...
import discord

# Token des Bots
TOKEN = "Musdnqdu8WDHzgBszasH8hH" (<- placeholder)


# Intents definieren
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True  # Damit der Bot auf Nachrichten reagieren kann

# Discord-Client initialisieren
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Minecraft"))
    print(f'{client.user} ist nun online!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    # Überprüfen, ob die Nachricht im Kanal "bot-chat" gesendet wurde
    if message.channel.name == 'botchat':
        if '$statistik' in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('Hier ist die aktuelle Statistik:')

# Bot starten
client.run(TOKEN)


Make sure you enable message content intents

"MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" is enabled

As mentioned in the comments by mousetail you need to enable the message content intent on the dev portal and inside your code:
intents.message_content = True


replace this:
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

with this:
prefix = '!'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)

if that doesnt work try using bot.run(TOKEN) instead of client.run(TOKEN)
hope this helped!
